# WPF Implicit selection of template using DataTemplate, but outside of 'List'

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, datatemplate

In my project, I have TreeView, which contains a tree of objects of various types (all subclassed from the same superclass).

To the right of my TreeView I would like to have a "panel" (at the moment I just have a Grid) which displays information about the object currently selected in the tree. I want to use DataTemplate, as in the second example on [this page](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=16), to adapt the layout & content of my "panel" based on the subclass type; however, I cannot find a suitable container (as I don't want a list control - I want to change my display for *one* item based on the selection in the treeview).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787500/datatemplate-without-listbox-itemssource) asks the same thing but I don't think the answer is suitable for me because I want the template to change dynamically depending on the type.

I.e. I was hoping for something like:

```
<[A Suitable Container] Margin="189,39,12,12" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem}">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:subclass1}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- subclass1 specific stuff -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:subclass2}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- subclass2 specific stuff -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</[A Suitable Container]>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
            <local:ViewA />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
            <local:ViewB />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```