# windows store app xaml template property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have defined custom `ListviewItemStyle`. 
In template of style there is a button

```
<Button x:Name="btnAbout"  Grid.Column="1"
        Style="{StaticResource GCAboutButton}"
        Visibility="Collapsed"     
        Command="{Binding DataContext.AboutCommand, ElementName=List}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Item}">
</Button>
```

In `VisualStateManager` `Visibitity` of this button is changed to `Visible`, in `Selecetd` state of `ListViewItem`.

ListView contain items of different types, derived from base Class, For example:

```
class Base; class Man: Base; class Woman:Base;
```

The problem is: 
button must be visible, when `SelectedItem` is Man, invisible, when selected item is Woman.
How can i get to the button defined in the template, from code. For example, frome `SelectionChanged` event of `ListView`.

Comment: You must use data binding on the `Visibility` property. You will probably need to define a converter to do that.

Comment: Define two new VisualStates for Man and Woman. In these VisualStates change the Visibility of button. Apply appropriate VisualState from SelectionChanged event.

Comment: @VictoryJessie Visual State is a parameter of ViewElement. How to get Selected View of listbox? i can get selected binded item, but not view.

Comment: Use GetTemplateChild(string childName) method to get button from template. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VictoryJessie You misunderstand, How can i get Template of ListViewItem, that is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Impllicit Data Templates. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175916/wpf-implicit-selection-of-template-using-datatemplate-but-outside-of-list) may also help.
The DataTemplate class has a DataType property that is very similar to the TargetType property of the Style class, so based on your type you can manage the template.