# MVVM Pattern with a class with 2 lists

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm

I wanted to ask how do i apply the MVVM Pattern for my Data Structure ?

I'm building a kind of a product configurator and i'm confused how to set this up because im new to MVVM and i need some basic tips or maybe some guides especially for like similar class structures.

The most confusing part is that i have a product which consists of two lists and i dont know how to build the correct ViewModel for it:

[image]

Some more information:

In my MainWindow i want to draw different products in my example its just one product. I think i will need own ViewModels for each type of product. The product should be changeable in runtime.

This is what i tried but i dont know if its in the right direction. I think i will defintely need ObservableCollections:

```
public class ProductOneViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double length;

    private List<Profil> listProfiles;

    private List<ItemLevel> listItemLevels;

    public List<Profil> ListeProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return listProfiles;
        }

        set
        {

            if (listProfiles == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            listProfiles = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("ListProfiles");
        }
    }


    public List<ItemLevel> ListItemLevels
    {
        get
        {
            return listItemLevels;
        }

        set
        {

            if (listItemLevels == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            listItemLevels = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("ListItemLevels");
        }
    }




    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: I would use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`, and you should *probably* make those read-only properties (it is correct for the majority of cases I've seen).  Other than that, what you have here isn't bad for an early attempt at MVVM.

Comment: The key thing with "list" type things in view models, is that you don't generally want the list *instance* to change once it is set, you care about the *contents* changing.    So those `OnPropertyChanged` calls won't pick  up adding or removing items from the list.  If you want to be aware of the lists contents changing, there are special events on `ObservableCollection<T>` that allow you to hook in and see updates, that's actually what the data-binding in WPF hooks in to.

Comment: Thank you thats one important information i needed

Comment: If different products can have actual different UI layouts (not just different data), you should create a base `Product` class that your real products (or product categories) inherit from.  Then you can use [implicit template binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175916/wpf-implicit-selection-of-template-using-datatemplate-but-outside-of-list) based on the sub-class of the model to easily and automatically pull in the UI.

Comment: @BradleyUffner do i have to change my list from my data structure too then or is it unecessary

Comment: The nice thing about MVVM is that is allows you to wrap almost any model.  for me, personally, I don't like my model classes to expose things like observable collections; I keep them as lists unless observability is an intrinsic part of what the model actually represents.  Opinions among developers on that can vary quite a bit though, so keep in mind that it is just my opinion, and not some hard rule.

Comment: It looks like you should have a look at some basic MVVM examples. Look at the demo from this article. It looks like what you need (skip part about selection manager, just look at demo project). https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1163874/Selection-Manager-for-WPF-MVVM

Comment: thank you thats exactly what i searched for